# Python. list indices must be integers or slices not tuple when none of the indices could possibly be tuple

Tags: python, excel, numpy, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I have created the excel using python so all the data there is correct:
here is the code for excel:

```
import openpyxl as exl
import random


book = exl.load_workbook("test2.xlsx")
sheet = book.active


for x in range(1,50000):
    number = random.uniform(-100,100)

    mycell = sheet.cell(row = x, column = 4)
    mycell.value = number

for x in range(1,50000):
    number = random.uniform(-50,150)

    mycell = sheet.cell(row = x, column = 5)
    mycell.value = number


book.save('test2.xlsx')
```

Then I am using python to scatter all the points from excel and apply clustering.
I Don't uderstand how can my list have any errors when i created it using python so there must be no mistake in there.
    import openpyxl as exl
    import random

```
import sklearn as skl
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import numpy as np

from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_score

book = exl.load_workbook("test2.xlsx")
sheet = book.active

coordinates = []

for row_var in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
    x = sheet.cell(row = row_var, column = 4).value
    y = sheet.cell(row=row_var, column = 5).value

    point = [x,y]
    coordinates.append(point)


kmeans = KMeans(init='k-means++', n_clusters=4, n_init=20).fit_predict(coordinates)
print(kmeans)
plt.scatter(coordinates[:,0], coordinates[:,1], c = kmeans, edgecolor = 'black')


score = silhouette_score(coordinates, kmeans)
print(score)


plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please post the complete stack trace here.

Comment: `coordinates` is a list. You can't slice it numpy-style. Try `coordinates = np.array(coordinates)` before your plot command.

Comment: Indexing with `x[0,1]` creates a tuple index, the equivalent of `x[(0,1)]`.  That kind of indexing is fine for numpy arrays, but not for Python lists.

Comment: The shortest would be `plt.scatter(*np.array(coordinates).T, c= ...)`

Answer (score 0):

Is this where you getting an error? 
`plt.scatter(coordinates[:,0], coordinates[:,1])`

If so, I would try:

```
x_coord = [i[0] for i in coordinates]
y_coord = [i[1] for i in coordinates]
plt.scatter(x_coord, y_coord)
```

You're storing the points as tuples in a list, not in a matrix/dataframe like object. `:,0` is a tuple that you are trying to use to access elements in a list.